# Django - Localize widget attribute

Tags: django, localization, django-forms, django-templates

I have a placeholder numeric value in a form field to serve as an example. That value is being passed as a widget attribute. Is there any way to have that value localized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found `django.utils.formats.number_format` to work.